# A scaling difference between MATLAB's pwelch and Python's SciPy welch

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, signal-processing

I'm having trouble in python with the `scipy.signal` method called **welch** (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html), which estimates the frequency spectrum of a time signal, because it does not (at all) provide the same output as MATLAB's method called **pwelch** (https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html), given the same parameters (window type (Hamming), window size, overlap, etc.). Beneath is my code in each language (the input is a real signal):

MATLAB:

```matlab
pxx_matlab = pwelch(w_in,4096,0.5*4096,4096)
```

(according to the documentation the default window in MATLAB's pwelch is hamming)

Python:

```py
from scipy import signal
f, pxx = signal.welch(w_in, fs=16000, window='hamming', nperseg=4096, noverlap=2048, nfft=4096, detrend=False)
```

This is the input data:

```py
np.random.seed(0)
w_in = np.random.randn(16000*10)
```

(I don't know how to attach CSV files)

Here are the results:
[image]

As you can see, the two signals differ by a scaling constant (well, almost a constant), which is about 34 dB (2544). I tried to link the constant to the sampling frequency `fs = 16000`, Nyquist frequency (8 kHz) or the window's length `4096`, overlap `2048` and their `10*np.log10` dB counterparts but to no avail.

Do you know why is there a constant scaling difference and to what does the constant equal (as a function of the parameters)?

Edit: the constant 34 dB seems to be independent of the data used, therefore it is very likely it is a function of the signal processing parameters (fs, window length, overlap etc).

Comment: 10*log10(2049) and 10*log10(2048) are approximately 33.11 dB

Comment: The following post on DSP Stack Exchange is relevant and useful, as it explains the scaling that MATLAB's pwelch does: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/61439/scaling-of-the-pwelch-function-in-matlab

Comment: Cross-posted on DSP SX: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/76194/a-scaling-difference-between-matlabs-pwelch-and-pythons-scipy-welch